# Getting text displayed to user from sharedpreference from listpreference

Tags: android, android-preferences

My question is very much similar to [Android listpreference - fetching value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761126/android-listpreference-fetching-value)

I've implemented OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener on Main Activity. Preference activity inflates preference.xml

On `public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences pref, String key)` on Main activity,

I can do:

`SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

intensity= Float.valueOf(prefs.getString("VIB_INTENSITY", "1.0"));`

to get the value. But like the linked question I want both the value and text displayed to user, i.e. value from both the array.

I can do like the accepted answer but I was wondering if there is any other built in methods.